# If I export a Word document (authored as a versioned document using Pages 4.1 on Lion),...

Tags: macos, pages, ms-office

will it open on Word on Windows?

I don't have a Word on Windows and I've only Pages on my Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is simply: yes, it will.